# window onload select div and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm currently working on an UI using HTML5 and jQuery. I try to make a load screen for my app, thus select a div in the onload event and fade it out, once the page is fully loaded.

My coding looks like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(myApp.init);
$(window).on("load", function () {
    console.log("load");
    $("div.loadScreen").fadeOut();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

<div class="loadScreen">
    <span>loading...</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.loadScreen {
  opacity:    1; 
  background: #123; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

It shows the log message "load", but the selection of the div doesn't work.

Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: For me it works. You have really no typo in your Project Code?

Comment: what do you mean by  'but the selection of the div doesn't work' ?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the first line of your jQuery/js and it worked:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXaoER?editors=1111

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
    console.log("load");
    $("div.loadScreen").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
div.loadScreen {
  opacity:    1; 
  background: #123; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

<div class="loadScreen">
    <span>loading...</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was no problem

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
    console.log("load");
    $("div.loadScreen").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
div.loadScreen {
  opacity:    1; 
  background: #123; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

<div class="loadScreen">
    <span>loading...</span>
</div>
```

in first line of code you use `$(document).ready(myApp.init);`, are you sure before loaded completely do any change in html file?

in your browser see console log for error that prevent to run successfully or if not seen , add more detail of your code in question.